# Does the tikz library `overlay-beamer-styles` support multiple fill colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

The following presentation depicts an empty circle emerging on frame 2. The color of the circle then proceeds to toggle between blue and red.

[image]

This presentation was produced with the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame \thepage}

  \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \draw[
      , ultra thick
      , visible on=<{2,3,5}>
      , fill=blue
      , fill on=<{3,5}>
      ] circle (2cm);

      \draw[
      , ultra thick
      , visible on=<{4, 6}>
      , fill=red
      , fill on=<{4, 6}>
      ] circle (2cm);

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here, the blue circles are defined separately from the red circles. I'm curious if it's possible to simplify this code by combining everything into one `\draw` command. I've tried doing

```
  \draw[
  , ultra thick
  , visible on=<{2-}>
  , fill=blue
  , fill on=<{3,5}>
  , fill=red
  , fill on=<{4, 6}>
  ] circle (2cm);
```

but this ignores all the blue circles:

[image]

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible with the `alt` key (which derives from `beamer`'s `\alt` command).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame \thepage}

  \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \draw[
      , ultra thick
      , visible on=<{2-6}>
      ,alt=<{3,5}>{fill=blue}{fill=red,fill on=<{4, 6}>}
      ] circle[radius=2cm];

    \end{tikzpicture}
  \]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way is use `preaction` and `postaction` options:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame \thepage}

    \[
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \draw[preaction={fill=blue, visible on=<{3,5}>},
        visible on=<2->,
        postaction={fill=red, visible on=<{4,6}>}
       ] circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```